# помощь с browserify

Tags: gulp, npm, ecmascript-6, babel

у меня два файла .js ,которые лежат в одной же папке.

app.js

```
import {foo} from 'custom';
foo();
```

custom.js

```
function foo(){
  $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}
```

И мне нужно их соеденить через gulpfile.js используя babel в том же таске.

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/app.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ["es2015"]
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
 });
```

Читал документацию но все равно не удалось реализовать идею.Может кто то помочь применить browserify в этом таске?

Answer (score 0):

```
const gulp           = require('gulp');
const babelify       = require('babelify');
const browserify     = require('browserify');
const source         = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer         = require('vinyl-buffer');
const sourcemaps     = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var config = {
    src:     __dirname + '/src/js/app.js', // тут исходник
    out:     __dirname + '/dist/js/app.js', // тут выходной файл
    srcmaps: __dirname + '/dist/js' // sourcemap'ы сохраняться будут сюда же

}

gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
    const bundler = browserify(config.src, {debug: true})
        .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015']})

    return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source(src.out))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(srcmaps, {addComment: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: не подскажете где можно подробно об этом прочитать,хочется также понимать что к чему

Comment: Кончено подскажу. В гугле. Могу расписать что зачем используется

Comment: буду очень благодарен

Comment: и тем не менее почему то срывается и не работает